# performance considerations when moving member functions that are used only by one other member function and making them local functions?

Tags: c++, function, local, member

Are there performance considerations when moving member functions of a class that are used only by one other member function of that class and making them local functions at the start of the function they are being used by instead?

http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Local_Functions_In_C.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's not. It's just a normal function call.

It's worth mentioning that you can't use local structs or classes as template arguments, so if you were thinking of using them for STL comparators then forget it :)

Comment: but you can in C++11 can't you? Otherwise lambdas would be useless.

Comment: @Yttrill, Why would that make lambdas useless? Lambdas are a separate concept than function objects, and while they are implemented as syntactic sugar for function objects, they are treated separately as far as the standard is concerned (so there is no rule about lambdas not being used as template arguments).